# Splitting payments in Stripe

Tags: shopify

Background, we are a platform that sells products from multiple retailers.
I specifically need the payment split into two PaymentIntents for each retailer so I can't take one payment intent and then split and send the payments.
Any way to authorize the amount and then create multiple orders with multiple PaymentIntent (which will add up to the original amount)? Maybe some other solution?

Is this possible?

I can't seem to figure out how to split the PaymentIntent on a single order.

Comment: Question, how do you add a single product against multiple retailers? Because the Payment is Intended for a single product. If there are Multiple products, each from a different retailer why do you want to split the payment in [x],[y] % of product and create intents for a single product. Please elaborate a bit more on this just so that we can understand the problem better. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! The order will have multiple items, each item coming from different retailers.
For legal reasons, each retailer needs to have a dedicated paymentintent for the item they sold so taking one payment and then splitting it up won't work.